# Using jQuery each to display images

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to display three images each in a row. For example, I am trying to get the page to look like this (I manually went ahead and typed out all the html I'm trying to get): https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3gFd.jpg

But when I try to use jQuery to append the images to try and make it appear like how it is in the previous screenshot, it displays like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ195.jpg

Obviously that is different than how I want it to be.

Here is my code (both the html and jQuery)

```
<div class="w3-container" id="album-header" style="display: none;">
    <h4 class="w3-text-black"></h4>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-top" style="display: none;">
    <div class="w3-third">
        <div class="w3-card-2" id="palbums">
            <!-- image here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$('#album-name').on('change', function() {
    // retrieve the images from the photo album selected
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/members/profile/get-photos-from-album",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  { 
            album_name: $('#album-name option:selected').val()
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        if (msg.photos == undefined) {
            $('#no-album-photos .w3-col m12').attr('style', 'display: initial;');
            $('#no-album-photos .w3-col m12 ').html("<p>No photos were found in the album</p>");

            return false;
        } else {
            $('#album-header').attr('style', 'display: initial;');

            $('#album-header h4').html("Photos in " + $('#album-name option:selected').text().split("_")[0] + ":");

            $('.w3-row-padding .w3-margin-top').attr('style', 'display: initial;');

            $.each(msg.photos, function(i, item) {
                $('div.w3-third').find('.w3-card-2').append('<img src="<?php echo $this->basePath() . '/images/profile/' . $this->identity() . '/albums/'; ?>' + $('#album-name option:selected').val() + '/' + msg.photos[i] + '" style="width: 100%;">');
            });
        }
    }).fail(function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```

I know the issue is within the $.each function but I am at a loss on how to fix this (after searching for any issues or tutorials on how to accomplish this but to no luck unfortunately).

The html I am trying to get for this would be like this:

```
<div class="w3-row padding w3-margin-top">
    <div class="w3-third">
        <div class="w3-card-2">
           <!-- image here -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-third">
        <div class="w3-card-2">
           <!-- image here -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-third">
       <div class="w3-card-2">
           <!-- image here -->
       </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<!-- after 3 in a row -->
<!-- make a new row -->
<div class="w3-row padding w3-margin-top">
    <div class="w3-third">
        <div class="w3-card-2">
           <!-- image here -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-third">
        <div class="w3-card-2">
           <!-- image here -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-third">
       <div class="w3-card-2">
           <!-- image here -->
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. If more information is needed, I can try and post more.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that your server isn't returning the same photo name 3 times? Because the each loop looks ok on the face of it

Comment: You mention you want rows but the way you are stacking your `divs` you will make columns which is the correct result you are getting.

Comment: No, it's returning all the images @ADyson

Comment: @CesarBielich I'm unsure of how to get it with rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stacking your `DIV`'s which will create columns so your code is working fine, it's your HTML that's wrong. You could use `float: left` to do this

```
<div class="w3-row padding w3-margin-top">
    <div class="w3-third" style="float: left">
        <div class="w3-card-2">
           Image1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-third" style="float: left">
        <div class="w3-card-2">
           Image2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-third" style="float: left">
       <div class="w3-card-2">
           Image3
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7kmmpaku/)

OR stylesheet it

```
.w3-third {
    float: left;
    max-height: 200px;
}
img {
    max-height: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that out and this is the output http://imgur.com/CxIwwqw

better than what I had but was trying to go for something like this: http://imgur.com/AsizGyy

Comment: It looks like your images have different heights which is going to do that. Do you want them all the same size?

Comment: yeah, I want them all the same size. I did it before, the class adjusts the image accordingly but I want three on the one line (or row) then go to another row (like this http://imgur.com/AsizGyy)

Comment: then you need to set `max-height: 200px` or any number that would be less than the max height of your shortest image. I edited my code

Comment: that came out better: http://imgur.com/0PCWJLm but do you see how some of the images have no bottom margin space? I would like to fix that

Comment: make your image height a little smaller and add some paddings to the bottom. I made the changes.

Comment: I guess this is about as good as it's going to get http://imgur.com/ubPiBny.. too bad about the last image in the first row, wish it could get moved up. Thanks though :)

Comment: I mean do you see the first two images in the 1st "row"? I'm wondering why the other images won't show up like that

Comment: Based on the shadow on the bottom edges it seems your images have white space on the bottom of them.

Comment: it's not the images, I don't know why the whitespace is showing underneath.

Answer (score 0):

> Try updating the line with the $.each function. Looks like you are
>   looping within the **div.w3-third** instead of the **div.w3-row**.

```
$(this).append('<div class="w3-third"><div class="w3-card-2"><img src="<?php echo $this->basePath() . '/images/profile/' . $this->identity() . '/albums/'; ?>' + $('#album-name option:selected').val() + '/' + msg.photos[i] + '" style="width: 100%;"></div></div>');
```

Though this is not the best implementation of building html with jQuery.

You don't need a new row each time. If your css class .w3-third which i assume is one-third of your row. You'll have something like this

**CSS**

```
.w3-third {
     width: 33.3%;
     float: left;
 }
```

Set the height of the image wrapper

```
    .w3-card-2 {
       height: 240px;
       margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
```

OR

```
.w3-card-2, .w3-card-2 img {
       height: 240px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes that looks way better than what I had but I am trying to get it to look like this: http://imgur.com/AsizGyy instead of like this http://imgur.com/CxIwwqw

The way it was that made it look like the one in http://imgur.com/AsizGyy was that it had three w3-third columns in one row then after that it made a new row. Does that help explain it better?

Comment: That means you have to set the min-height or height in your css for the image wrapper and / or the image itself. I've updated the answer to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
.w3-third {
float: left;
width:30%;
max-height: 200px;
pading:0;
}
img {
width:100%;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
max-height: 150px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea why the 1st two images are spaced correctly but the others aren't? http://imgur.com/zXgBMZF if you can see how the 1st two have the right space beneath the 2nd row but the rest don't. Any idea?

Comment: Yes this is because the width of the 3 images more than the width of main div I updated the code but it will leave right space you have to correct it